# Why controls do not want to get removed?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am trying to remove all the controls that are contained in my winform panel but they simply do not want to get removed - some of them are removed and some of them not. I have tried 2 approaches already and nothing:

1. foreach

   ```
   foreach (Control controlEntry in this.contentsPanel.Controls)
   {
       this.contentsPanel.Controls.Remove(controlEntry);
   }
   ```
2. for

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < this.contentsPanel.Controls.Count; i++)
   {
       this.contentsPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
   }
   ```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: what do you mean by "want", they don't get removed or they throw an error when you do it?

Comment: What exactly happens? Exactly.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your loop to ensure that your logic is correct?

Comment: Because they like their cozy container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to watch out for code like this, removing controls from their container like this produces an unrecoverable resource leak.  Controls.Remove/At(), or the Controls.Clear() method as suggested by other posters, removes the control from the collection and re-hosts it to the "parking window".  An otherwise invisible window where the native window can find a hospitable home without having to be destroyed.  Ready to be re-hosted on another parent.

Which is the trap, you typically don't move it to another parent.  The control will continue to survive on the parking window, consuming native Windows resources.  The garbage collector cannot recover these resources.  Eventually your program will crash when Windows refuses to provide more windows to your process.  The exception message will say "Error creating handle".

Instead, you must *dispose* the control.  Which also automatically removes the control from its parent.  The proper code is:

```
 while (contentsPanel.Controls.Count > 0) contentsPanel.Controls[0].Dispose();
```

Or iterate backwards if you find this a bit too bizarre looking.

Comment: That is a good point, I didn't know clear didn't disposed the instances. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Each time you remove control from collection, the collection changes. When you remove 1st element of `Controls`, 2nd element becomes 1st, so when you proceed to delete 2nd control, you are in fact removing 3rd element from original collection (skipping 2nd element).

If you want to remove all controls contained in collection, use `this.contentsPanel.Controls.Clear()`. If you want to remove controls by their indices in `ControlCollection`, first select controls to remove to separate list or array and then remove them.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove them all then just do

```
this.contentsPanel.Controls.Clear()
```

Answer (score 3):

The foreach will fail because you are changing the collection, which breaks the iterator.

The for fails because you are only removing every other item; consider: i=0, you remove the zeroth item. Now the item that **was** item 1 is item 0 - so when you remove item 1 (next loop iteration) you have jumped one.

Short version: use `Clear()`:

```
contentsPanel.Controls.Clear();
```

Longer version: iterate backwards:

```
for(int i=contentsPanel.Controls.Count-1; i>=0;i--) {
   contentsPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

The first (Clear) is simpler.

Comment: or iterate forwards and skip incrementing i. In this case I agree clears is of course the way to go

Comment: @RuneFS if the collection was backed by a linked list, that would be great. But since most collections are backed by an array, removing item 0 each time means lots of copying.

Comment: yeah I agree no need to copy when it can easily be avoided

Answer (score 0):

In case of webbrowser control, file is not free with
contentsPanel.Controls.Clear();
or with
contentsPanel.Controls.Remove(i);

use
while (contentsPanel.Controls.Count > 0) contentsPanel.Controls[0].Dispose();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).