# GDI+ object leak (font, brush)

Tags: .net, gdi, resource-leak

I encounter GDI font and brush leaks in my application. How can I find the created (and note disposed) objects in my source code?

I do not have any `toHFont` calls and all access to Graphics is encapsuled in a using statement. I know its brush and font from tools like GDIView and .NET Memory Profiler - but they do not say which where the leaked object was created in my source code.

I am using C# in VS2008, .NET 3.5.

Comment: How is this something you couldn't find back with a code review.  Surely you only use them in select places in your code?  You are otherwise going to need a *real* memory profiler to get past this hump, GDIView and .NET MP don't meet that bar.  Real = money.

Comment: I use fonts with `Graphics` and to assign a font to a control. Brushes are used just in `Graphics`. I also try to reuse them as they are often static variables so I do not get the point which leak.

Comment: A static variable is an intentional leak.  It forever holds a reference to the brush object.  There's no real point in doing this, creating a brush object is very cheap, takes a microsecond.

Comment: Why is it an intentional leak as it gets used again and again. There are only like 10 variables but GDI leaks several hundreds of fonts.

Comment: Fonts are cached by Winforms because they are not cheap to allocate.  Do you actually get your program to crash when you use it long enough?  If you don't then it is not a leak.

Comment: I have a part where there are dynamically created Textboxes on the form and everytime I go there the number GDI objects increases without them ever being release. I also changed all static Font instances to use a 'fresh' `new Font`. But it does not help although I just create standard Labels and TextBoxes.

Comment: Are you calling Dispose() on any controls that you remove?  Required.

Comment: Hmm, I changed the `Controls.Clear()` to a recursive `control.Dispose()` and the situation has improved (but is not solved). I wonder why the normal `Controls.Clear()` does not do that for itself but I will now search for all the control-removing sections.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466343/why-controls-do-not-want-to-get-removed/8466478#8466478

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to wrap your fonts and brushes in Using / End Using blocks.

Comment: As I use some brushes and fonts again and again I have put them into static variables so that they are created less often and are more reused. So I cannot put them into using-blocks (what I try to do with every resource which implements IDisposable).