# When I switch between forms some events are not working

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

**Scenario:**

I have a Form (`Form1`) which consists of following elements.

A panel called `panel1`, four buttons as `btnLoadForm2`, `btnLoadForm3`, `btnSave`, `btnDelete`.

When I click the `btnLoadForm2` or `btnLoadForm3` it loads the `Form2` or `Form3` into `panel1` in `Form1`.

**But the Problem is**

For exmaple;

When I work with the first loaded Form doesn't matter which one is loaded in the panel (Form2 or Form3) both btnSave and btnDelete events are working. But When I switch the Form non of button events are working.

**Code:**

```
// Codes in Form1 which consists of panel1 and all other buttons

   private void btnloadForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        var form = panel1.Controls.OfType<Form>().First();

        if (form.Name != "Form2")
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            Form newForm = new Form2();
            newForm.TopLevel = false;
            newForm.Visible = true;
            panel1.Controls.Add(newForm);
        }
    }

   private void btnloadForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
   {
        var form = panel1.Controls.OfType<Form>().First();

        if (form.Name != "Form3")
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            Form newForm = new Form3();
            newForm.TopLevel = false;
            newForm.Visible = true;
            panel1.Controls.Add(newForm);
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = panel1.Controls.OfType<Form>().First();

        if (form.Name == "Form2")
        {
            Form2 f2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault();
            f2.Save();
        }

        else if (form.Name == "Form2")
        {
            Form3 f3 = (Form3)Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form3>().FirstOrDefault();
            f3.Save();
        }
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = panel1.Controls.OfType<Form>().First();

        if (form.Name == "Form2")
        {
            Form2 f2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault();
            f2.Delete();
        }

        else if (form.Name == "Form3")
        {
            Form3 f3 = (Form3)Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form3>().FirstOrDefault();
            f3.Delete();
        }
    }
```

Please anyone tell me whats wrong with my code..

I'm not going to write the codes in my `Form2` and `Form3`..  all codes are working when the Forms are loaded into the `Form1.Panel1` in my first attempt.

Comment: It's generally an odd idea to have one *form* inside another. I would suggest just using panels instead of forms - a form is typically a top-level window.

Comment: Using Controls.Clear() is a bug.  That only removes the form from the panel, it doesn't dispose it.  So when you next use the Application.OpenForms property, you'll find these old objects back.  You *must* use Dispose() to completely destroy the form object.  And don't use OpenForms, there is no point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why controls do not want to get removed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466343/why-controls-do-not-want-to-get-removed)

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to display the form as opposed to adding it as control to a panel.

so do something like:

```
newForm.Show();
```

or

```
newForm.ShowDialog();
```